# Syntax error on token with array

Tags: java, arrays

I am new at coding in Java. I am trying to write a program that calculates the first 400 multiples of the number 13 and stores them in an array with ints. 
I cannot find why there are two errors in this class, I think I have made no mistakes.. can anyone help please?
the first error (three errors on this line) is on

```
System.out.println("the first 400 multiples of 13:" );
```

> Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token
>   Syntax error on token ""the first 400 multiples of 13:"", delete this token
>   Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

and the second one is on the last }

**where it says:**

> Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

```
public class multiples_of_13 {
 int[] thirteens = new int[400];
 int numFound = 0;
 // candidate: the number that might be a multiple
 // of 13
 int candidate = 1;

 System.out.println("the first 400 multiples of 13:" );

 while (numFound < 400) {
     if (candidate % 13 == 0) {
         thirteens[numFound] = candidate;
         numFound++;
     }
     candidate++;
 }
 System.out.println("First 400 multiples of 13:");
 for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
    System.out.print(thirteens[i] + " ");
 }
}
```

Comment: I have added this and then it is ok, but what about the first errors?
I don't think I have written something wrong.

Comment: You need a `main` method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put the code into a `main` method as it is the entry of your program.

On that, the instructions are not allowed inside the body of the class, but inside one of its methods or blocks.

---

### Solution

```
public class multiples_of_13 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] thirteens = new int[400];
        int numFound = 0;
        // candidate: the number that might be a multiple
        // of 13
        int candidate = 1;

        System.out.println("the first 400 multiples of 13:" );

        while (numFound < 400) {
            if (candidate % 13 == 0) {
                thirteens[numFound] = candidate;
                numFound++;
            }
            candidate++;
        }
        System.out.println("First 400 multiples of 13:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
            System.out.print(thirteens[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't write statements directly in class.You need to add a method where you can put these statements to work.

To resolve this,add a main method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class multiples_of_13 {
    public void findMultiples() {
        int[] thirteens = new int[400];
        int numFound = 0;
        // candidate: the number that might be a multiple
        // of 13
        int candidate = 1;

        System.out.println("the first 400 multiples of 13:" );

        while (numFound < 400) {
            if (candidate % 13 == 0) {
                thirteens[numFound] = candidate;
                numFound++;
            }
            candidate++;
        }
        System.out.println("First 400 multiples of 13:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
            System.out.print(thirteens[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

you cannot directly add statements in java. hence, enclose them in a function